# Showing "ssh packet_write_wait broken pipe" error while taking button input on Pi

Tags: gpio, ssh, pi-b+, gpiozero

I was trying to write a program which can take input from button. Here is the code:

```
from gpiozero import Button
btn = Button(4)
while True:
    btn.wait_for_press()
    print('You pressed me')
    btn.wait_for_release()
    print('You released me')
```

Whenever I am pressing the button, my ssh connection gets freezes for a few seconds and gets terminated with the following error message.

**"ssh packet_write_wait broken pipe"**
Please help!

*I am on Raspbian stretch, Pi model 1 B+*.

Connection is as follows:

ground pin ---> button ---> pin 4 [BCM]

I can see every time when I press button, the red system LED shuts down for that period.

Answer (score 3):

If you are connecting pin 4 (5v) to ground pressing the button is shorting your power supply.

The power supply will then shutdown and cut power to the Pi -- killing your ssh connection.

Then it reboots after you release the button and you can repeat the process.

If you want GPIO 4 I think that is pin 7.